# How to know when onNext() is called on downstream subscribers?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

So I have an `Observable`. I would like to know when *every* downstream subscribers `onNext` calls are about to be made, both for measuring the amount of time each downstream subscriber takes and for backpressure purposes.

`Observable.lift` gets me halfway - I can wrap each individual subscriber with my own `Subscriber`, as in the example below. This won't notify me when all downstream subscribers have completed their `onNext` calls, without me having to do some bookkeeping of my own though.

```
eventObservable.lift(subscriber -> new Subscriber<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            request(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Event event) {
            subscriber.onNext(event);
            request(1);
        }
    });
```

Is there a good way to do this (and is it even a smart approach)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your `eventObservable` and how are your events emitted?

Answer (score 3):

arent doOnXXX methods like doOnNext http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#doOnNext%28rx.functions.Action1%29 enough for your purposes? This way you can intercept onNext and other events.

Comment: I can intercept onNext using `Obervable.lift` as well. I'm not sure what the doOnXXX will add here...